# Does the front hydraulic brake hose also requires foam to avoid noise?

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I watched a few videos of hydraulic brakes installation and notice that people install a foam pipe over the hose for the rear brakes.

My hydraulic brake set has only one foam.

Should I install the foam on the front hose to avoid it hitting against the fork and consequently making noise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the foam for the rear brake hose. The rear brake hose is really long and is suspended inside the down tube. It will sag and bounce against the tube on every little bump, making noise and driving you crazy. (Though if you are replacing an existing brakes, the old hose may already have foam that you can re-use).

The front brake hose will generally have a channel or clip on the fork that it should be routed through that will keep it in position. You can also put some clear tape on the hose or frame to protect the frame if you're really worried about it.

Also, trimming the front and rear hoses will be necessary in most cases. That also requires you to bleed the brakes after. You will want to lookup how to do that and get the right tools and supplies for it all ahead of time. Bleeding brakes properly can be frustrating for home mechanics and it's very necessary to have safe brakes. It may be cheaper and worthwhile to pay a professional to do it unless you plan to do this again in the future or desire to do it yourself.